# UIActionSheet in iPad Popovercontroller scrolling bug

Tags: ipad, ios6, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I am trying to present an actionsheet from a UIBarButtonItem within a UITextView keyboard input accessory.

I have two different action sheets of commonly used strings that I want to show as a quick enter of sorts.

When the action sheet is presented, it contains buttons and no scroll feature. If it is presented in landscape, AND THEN rotated, or subsequently presented in any orientation it presents itself with a scroll bar.

My thought is that the list within the actionsheet is short enough that it COULD be presented within the bounds of the entire view (clipped by the keyboard), and while it is presented in landscape that condition would not be true so it displays as a scrollable view.

I am using the following to present my action sheet

```
[actionSheetEnglish showFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:NO];
```

Has anyone been able to implement a small area scrollable UIActionSheet on the iPad?
The actionsheet works properly on the iPhone so I know it is set up properly.